# How to rename with prefix/suffix?

Tags: bash, rename, filenames, prefix, mv

How do I do `mv original.filename new.original.filename` without retyping the original filename?

I would imagine being able to do something like `mv -p=new. original.filename` or perhaps `mv original.filename new.~` or whatever - but I can't see anything like this after looking at `man mv` / `info mv` pages.

Of course, I could write a shell script to do this, but isn't there an existing command/flag for it?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

In Bash and zsh you can do this with [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).  This simply expands a list of items in braces.  For example:

```
# echo {vanilla,chocolate,strawberry}-ice-cream
vanilla-ice-cream chocolate-ice-cream strawberry-ice-cream
```

So you can do your rename as follows:

```
mv {,new.}original.filename
```

as this expands to:

```
mv original.filename new.original.filename
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be the best solution - also works with ksh.

Comment: What this does not do is work with wild cards.  That is, in a directory containing filenames a, b, c, using "echo {,new.}*" yields the list "a b c new.*" (because file name generation via brace expansion occurs before expanding wild card characters - at least by inference).

Comment: Since months I'm looking for such a solution only using basic shell functionality... I would have never come up with something that simple, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Brace Expansion :-) exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I love the example. I'm feeling in the mood to go to Baskin Robbins during my lunchbreak now.

Comment: Serious question though - what `.bashrc` line would you need to get tab completion to expand it, so you can see what you are "really" going to execute.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You have to use bash scripting to act on multiple files, see [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208220/2436175)

Comment: I'm not a fan of tricks like this unless you use things like this regularly. The number of times I need to use this is small so I rather have a more straight forward solution that I have more of a chance of remembering.

Answer (score 201):

You could use the `rename(1)` command:

```
rename 's/(.*)$/new.$1/' original.filename
```

**Edit:** If `rename` isn't available and you have to rename more than one file, shell scripting can really be short and simple for this. For example, to rename all `*.jpg` to `prefix_*.jpg` in the current directory:

```
for filename in *.jpg; do mv "$filename" "prefix_${filename}"; done;
```

or also, leveraging from [Dave Webb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208260/2436175) and using brace expansion:

```
for filename in *.jpg; do mv {,prefix_}"$filename"; done;
```

Comment: Installed graphite this weekend, and they have a step that's essentially ("copy all the *.example files into the conf folder, removing the example suffix").  Real lazy on their part, but `rename 's/(.*).example/$1/' *.example` saved me from the tedium.

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Comment: I don't think you need the first `$` in this scenario. So just `'s/(.*)/new.$1/'`

Comment: `rename` command does not work on my RHEL 6 machine. Are there any different versions of this command? The `for ... done` worked for me.

Comment: For those looking for the suffix version: `for filename in *.jpg; do mv "$filename" "${filename}_suffix"; done;`

Comment: I recommend running `for filename in *.jpg; do echo "prefix_${filename}"; done;` first as a dry run to see that you get what you expect

Comment: @basZero that won't work you will get `[filename].jpg_suffix`

Comment: The single quotes on `rename` command are important to avoid shell expansion

Answer (score 26):

You can achieve a unix compatible multiple file rename (using wildcards) by creating a for loop:

```
for file in *; do
  mv $file new.${file%%}
done
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and [what Simon Lehmann already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208181/how-to-rename-with-prefix-suffix#208220)?

Comment: This works great. What doe ```${file%%}``` do? Seem similar to simply ${file}

Comment: I'm curious about ${file%%} as well

Comment: [The `%%` looks like a mistake here to me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952009/4386278)

Answer (score 10):

I've seen people mention a `rename` command, but it is not routinely available on Unix systems (as opposed to Linux systems, say, or Cygwin - on both of which, rename is an executable rather than a script).  That version of `rename` has a fairly limited functionality:

```
rename from to file ...
```

It replaces the *from* part of the file names with the *to*, and the example given in the man page is:

```
rename foo foo0 foo? foo??
```

This renames foo1 to foo01, and foo10 to foo010, etc.

I use a Perl script called `rename`, which I originally dug out from the first edition Camel book, circa 1992, and then extended, to rename files.

```
#!/bin/perl -w
#
# @(#)$Id: rename.pl,v 1.7 2008/02/16 07:53:08 jleffler Exp $
#
# Rename files using a Perl substitute or transliterate command

use strict;
use Getopt::Std;

my(%opts);
my($usage) = "Usage: $0 [-fnxV] perlexpr [filenames]\n";
my($force) = 0;
my($noexc) = 0;
my($trace) = 0;

die $usage unless getopts('fnxV', \%opts);

if ($opts{V})
{
    printf "%s\n", q'RENAME Version $Revision: 1.7 $ ($Date: 2008/02/16 07:53:08 $)';
    exit 0;
}
$force = 1 if ($opts{f});
$noexc = 1 if ($opts{n});
$trace = 1 if ($opts{x});

my($op) = shift;
die $usage unless defined $op;

if (!@ARGV) {
    @ARGV = <STDIN>;
    chop(@ARGV);
}

for (@ARGV)
{
    if (-e $_ || -l $_)
    {
        my($was) = $_;
        eval $op;
        die $@ if $@;
        next if ($was eq $_);
        if ($force == 0 && -f $_)
        {
            print STDERR "rename failed: $was - $_ exists\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "+ $was --> $_\n" if $trace;
            print STDERR "rename failed: $was - $!\n"
                unless ($noexc || rename($was, $_));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print STDERR "$_ - $!\n";
    }
}
```

This allows you to write any Perl substitute or transliterate command to map file names.
In the specific example requested, you'd use:

```
rename 's/^/new./' original.filename
```

Comment: Thanks, if I could accept a second answer this would be it.

I wanted a standard command as something that will just work on anything I might use, but I can put this script on the machines I do use frequently and it will still be helpful.

Comment: [James Wong](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6486307/james-wong) notes that for Arch Linux, you could just download and install this script via `pacman` using:

`pacman -Sy perl-rename`.

Then add an alias to it in your bashrc:
`alias rename='perl-rename'`

Comment: what if "from" or "to" are empty strings, i.e. you want to append something to each filename or remove something completely

Comment: @Troyseph — to append `'.html` to the file names, use `'s/$/.html/'` — to remove `tmp` from everywhere in the file names, use `'s/tmp//g'` (find `tmp` and replace with nothing everywhere).

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to bulk rename files in directory is:

```
ls | xargs -I fileName mv fileName fileName.suffix
```

Answer (score 8):

I know there is great answers here but I found no reference to handle filename extensions when adding suffix.

I needed to add '_en' suffix to all `wav` files in a folder before the file extension.

The magic is here: `%.*`

`for filename in *.wav; do mv $filename ${filename%.*}_en.wav; done;`

If you need to handle different file extensions, check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56812/157775) answer. A bit less intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

If it's open to a modification, you could use a suffix instead of a prefix. Then you could use tab-completion to get the original filename and add the suffix.

Otherwise, no this isn't something that is supported by the mv command. A simple shell script could cope though.

Comment: Often I want both, but primarily the prefix - as you say, tab completion can handle suffixes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like any of the other answers.
My take is that you want a vanilla bash solution. So here you go!

Try this with echo first to see what is going to happen!
Test your command before you use it on thousands of files!

**Remove the './' if you want to put in a prefix**
`find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo prefix_${0#./}' {} \;`

In the question asked, `prefix_` is `new.` so the command becomes
`find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 new.${0#./}' {} \;`

**Remove the extension if you want to put something after it**
`find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo ${0%.*}_suffix.${0##*.}' {} \;`

Now to use this to rename just replace echo with `mv $0`.

EXAMPLE:
`find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv $0 1.${0#./}' {} \;`

Inspired by:
https://gist.github.com/larshaendler/723d2ec447c3c694b71dc6e3bc3aadc9

Comment: This answer has been helpful to me. A note: for the prefix example you run the command for ALL files, and don't check that only intended files are affected. What I mean is that you might want to add an extra check for `-name 'original*'`, like so: `find . -type f -name 'original*' -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 new.${0#./}' {} \;`.

Answer (score 1):

In  my  case  I  have  a  group of files  which needs  to be  renamed before  I can  work  with  them. Each  file has  its  own  role  in  group and  has  its  own  pattern.

As  result  I  have  a  list  of  rename  commands like  this:

```
f=`ls *canctn[0-9]*`   ;  mv $f  CNLC.$f
f=`ls *acustb[0-9]*`   ;  mv $f  CATB.$f
f=`ls *accusgtb[0-9]*` ;  mv $f  CATB.$f
f=`ls *acus[0-9]*`     ;  mv $f  CAUS.$f
```

Try  this also :

```
f=MyFileName; mv $f {pref1,pref2}$f{suf1,suf2}
```

This  will produce  all combinations with  prefixes  and  suffixes:

```
pref1.MyFileName.suf1
...
pref2.MyFileName.suf2
```

Another  way to solve same  problem is to create  mapping array  and  add corespondent  prefix  for  each  file type  as  shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset masks
typeset -A masks
masks[ip[0-9]]=ip
masks[iaf_usg[0-9]]=ip_usg
masks[ipusg[0-9]]=ip_usg
...
for fileMask in ${!masks[*]}; 
do  
registryEntry="${masks[$fileMask]}";
fileName=*${fileMask}*
[ -e ${fileName} ] &&  mv ${fileName} ${registryEntry}.${fileName}  
done
```

Comment: As far as I can tell  `f=\`ls *canctn[0-9]*\`   ;  mv $f  CNLC.$f` only works if it matches a single file

Comment: thats true.  to avoid  that you  can  use find  <code>  find * -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*canctn[0-9]*" -exec echo mv {} CNLC.$(basename {}) \;    </code>  But  this  because  too big  for  a  compact  repetitive task.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk rename files bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# USAGE: cd FILESDIRECTORY; RENAMERFILEPATH/MultipleFileRenamer.sh FILENAMEPREFIX INITNUMBER
# USAGE EXAMPLE: cd PHOTOS; /home/Desktop/MultipleFileRenamer.sh 2016_
# VERSION: 2016.03.05.
# COPYRIGHT: Harkály Gergő | mangoRDI (https://wwww.mangordi.com/) 

# check isset INITNUMBER argument, if not, set 1 | INITNUMBER is the first number after renaming
if [ -z "$2" ]
    then i=1;
else
    i=$2;
fi

# counts the files to set leading zeros before number | max 1000 files
count=$(ls -l * | wc -l)
if [ $count -lt 10 ]
    then zeros=1;
else
    if [ $count -lt 100 ]
        then zeros=2;
    else
        zeros=3
    fi
fi

# rename script
for file in *
do
    mv $file $1_$(printf %0"$zeros"d.%s ${i%.*} ${file##*.})
    let i="$i+1"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This expands a bit on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208220/327074) here and combines it with [another answer from Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131620/8224).

This is designed as a way to get more power whilst relying on the simplest of commands and still a one-liner.

##### Add a prefix

Dry-run command ;)

```bash
for old in *.jpg; do new=`echo $old | sed -e's/^/prefix_/'`; echo "$old -- $new"; done
```

For real:

```bash
for old in *.jpg; do new=`echo $old | sed -e's/^/prefix_/'`; mv "$old" "$new"; done
```

This uses [`sed` search and replace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159369/8224) to replace the start of the string `^` with `prefix_`.

##### Add a suffix

This is useful because you get the additional power of `sed` so that you can use the same pattern to add a suffix:

```bash
# \1 might be $1 for you
for old in *.jpg; do new=`echo $old | sed -e's/(.jpg)$/_suffix\1/'`; mv "$old" "$new"; done
```

If you're less familiar with `sed`, this is equivalent to:

```bash
for old in *.jpg; do new=`echo $old | sed -e's/.jpg$/_suffix.jpg/'`; mv "$old" "$new"; done
```

##### Remove a prefix/suffix

Now should you mess up with the previous commands you can remove a prefix/suffix:

```bash
for old in *.jpg; do new=`echo $old | sed -e's/^prefix_//'`; mv "$old" "$new"; done
```