# Rename files in shell

Tags: shell, rename

I've folder and file structure like

```
Folder/1/fileNameOne.ext
Folder/2/fileNameTwo.ext
Folder/3/fileNameThree.ext
...
```

How can I rename the files such that the output becomes

```
Folder/1_fileNameOne.ext
Folder/2_fileNameTwo.ext
Folder/3_fileNameThree.ext
...
```

How can this be achieved in linux shell?

Comment: also asked on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/280333/10127)

Comment: I've added solution from [AskUbuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15953333/1433665)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This solution from [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280333/rename-files-in-group/280348?noredirect=1#280348) worked for me.**

Here is a bash script that does that:

***Note: This script does not work if any of the file names contain spaces.***

```
#! /bin/bash

# Only go through the directories in the current directory.
for dir in $(find ./ -type d)
do
    # Remove the first two characters. 
    # Initially, $dir = "./directory_name".
    # After this step, $dir = "directory_name".
    dir="${dir:2}"

    # Skip if $dir is empty. Only happens when $dir = "./" initially.
    if [ ! $dir ]
    then
        continue
    fi

    # Go through all the files in the directory.
    for file in $(ls -d $dir/*)
    do
        # Replace / with _
        # For example, if $file = "dir/filename", then $new_file = "dir_filename"
        # where $dir = dir
        new_file="${file/\//_}"

        # Move the file.
        mv $file $new_file
    done

    # Remove the directory.
    rm -rf $dir
done
```

- Copy-paste the script in a file.
- Make it executable using

```
chmod +x file_name
```

- Move the script to the destination directory. In your case this should be inside `Folder/`.
- Run the script using `./file_name`.

Answer (score 2):

How many different ways do you want to do it?

If the names contain no spaces or newlines or other problematic characters, and the intermediate directories are always single digits, and if you have the list of the files to be renamed in a file `file.list` with one name per line, then one of many possible ways to do the renaming is:

```
sed 's%\(.*\)/\([0-9]\)/\(.*\)%mv \1/\2/\3 \1/\2_\3%' file.list | sh -x
```

You'd avoid running the command through the shell until you're sure it will do what you want; just look at the generated script until its right.

There is also a command called `rename` — unfortunately, there are several implementations, not all equally powerful.  If you've got the one based on Perl (using a Perl regex to map the old name to the new name) you'd be able to use:

```
rename 's%/(\d)/%/${1}_%' $(< file.list)
```

Comment: I was just about to ask you out of curiosity if any of the `rename`s could do this (I never use them myself), since I was sure you would know. Your edit was faster :-)

Comment: +1. Can't help learing more and more every day. `rename` is a command I did not know and for these cases is very powerful.

Comment: I use the version I cribbed from the 1st Edition of the Camel Book (the original Programming Perl, for Perl 4), though I've mildly updated it since then.  See [How to rename with prefix/suffix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208181/how-to-rename-with-prefix-suffix/208389#208389) for the source.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, but I'm having hard time implementing your idea. Suppose I'm at `MainFolder` and I don't have any `file.list`, how can I rename?
I'm using Ubuntu and found out `rename` uses `Perl` expressions

Comment: `find Folder -type f | sed ...`?  Apply other criteria on the `find` as you need. Or use `find Folder -type f -exec rename 's%...%' {} +`.  Or ... there are other options too.  With `rename`, the `find -exec` is probably neatest.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop as follows:

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r line
do
    mv "$line" "${line%/*}_${line##*/}"
done < <(find Folder -type f -print0)
```

This method handle spaces, newlines and other special characters in the file names and the intermediate directories don't necessarily have to be single digits.

Answer (score 1):

This may work if the name is always the same, ie "file":

```
for i in {1..3};
do
    mv $i/file ${i}_file
done
```

If you have more dirs on a number range, change `{1..3}` for `{x..y}`.

I use `${i}_file` instead of `$i_file` because it would consider `$i_file` a variable of name `i_file`, while we just want `i` to be the variable and `file` and text attached to it.

Comment: Update your question with them!