# Check for dots in the file name and remove them (on Linux)

Tags: linux, bash

I found a bash script for my Synology NAS that is looking for *.mp4 files in a folder, strips the video out and saves them as *.m4a. (The purpose is an automatic 'YouTube to podcast converter').

```
for f in *.mp4; do mv -- "$f" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d -r "${f}") $f"; done
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -acodec copy "${f%.mp4}.m4a"; done
```

Sometimes the *.mp4 file names contain periods, e.g. 'This video...mp4', resulting in the podcast player not recognizing such files.

Is there a line I can add to the script to remove period(s) in front of the extension or to just remove them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extension from `${f}`, then delete or substitute all dots, then add the extension back when you rename the files essentially dealing with all but the last dot:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.mp4; do
        f=${f%.mp4}
        mv -- "${f}.mp4" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d -r "${f}.mp4") ${f//./_}.mp4"
done
for f in *.mp4; do
        ffmpeg -i "${f}" -vn -acodec copy "${f%.mp4}.m4a"
done
```

Obviously this only works for a single extension (`.mp4` in this case).

Comment: You, Sir, are a genious. Dankeschön.

Comment: nice usage of the `--` +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `rename` command to replace multiple consecutive dots with just one:

```
rename 's/\.+/./g' *.mp4
```

If you have `perl` installed and you cannot find `rename`, try also `prename`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the command line. Unfortunately my build of linux doesn't seem to support the rename command (not found). Cheers

Comment: Try `prerename`, of which `rename` is an alias. It is installed with `perl` package in Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: This is a good solution if you've got the Perl-based `rename` command.  Unfortunately, there are some under-powered variants called `rename` that don't use Perl regular expressions which are ... well, less satisfactory than the Perl-based commands of the same name.  See [How to rename with prefix/suffix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208181/how-to-rename-with-prefix-suffix/208389#208389) for a usable Perl `rename`.

Comment: What does `perl -v` says? If you cannot find it, I've pasted a copy here: http://codepad.org/IWaCTnbY

Comment: Thanks Stefano. It also wouldn't find 'prerename'. perl -v says 'This is perl, v5.8.6 built for MARVELL_88F6281' I'm not sure how to handle perl scripts, never did this before.

Comment: Nice! Download the script linked above, drop it in a folder, make it executable with `chmod +x rename.pl` and try calling it.

Comment: Noticed now: `prename`, not `prerename`! If you have `prename` you are ok.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo, the `${f}` is not outside any quotes: the `$()` runs in a subshell, so you effectively get a new "scope" for quotes.

Comment: I had to install rename using `sudo apt install rename`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, which uses tr to remove any periods in the filename:

```
for f in *.mp4; do mv -- "$f" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d -r "${f}") $f"; done
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -acodec copy "`echo "$f" | tr -d "\."`.m4a"; done
```

Comment: `convert.sh: line 2: tr: not found` It seems that my version of linux doesn't know very much linux at all..

Comment: Missing the tr utility?  That's unfortunate.  This is a common problem with stripped down embedded distributions.

Comment: @user2359595: Truly, if you don't have `tr`, your system is so hobbled that you'll have to work around any posted solution that assumes a set of POSIX utilities.

Comment: `tr` no, but `ffmpeg` yes. How nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this answer [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1285062&p=8067268#post8067268).
You can use the `rename` package by installing it using the following command.

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Then go to the directory containing the files and use the following command:

```
rename 's/\.(?!mp4$)/ /g' *.mp4
```