# how to change files names using pattern in Mac OS?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, file, terminal

I have 55 files named:

```
result_fresh_1.txt 
... 
result_fresh_55.txt
```

I want to rename them to:

```
result_bl_1.txt 
... 
result_bl_55.txt
```

how can I do this automatically?

Comment: by writing some code...

Comment: try combining awk and substr or regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in result_fresh_*.txt
do
    mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed 's/_fresh_/_bl_/')
done
```

I have a [Perl-based `rename` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208181/how-to-rename-with-prefix-suffix/208389#208389) (also available on Linux machines, so that equivalent source must be available elsewhere too) that would reduce it to:

```
rename 's/_fresh_/_bl_/' result_fresh_*.txt
```

There aren't any spaces in the names shown, but the code would work sanely unless the names included newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for f1 in $(echo {1..55});do
 if [ -f "result_fresh_$f1.txt" ];then
   mv result_fresh_$f1.txt result_b1_$f1.txt
 fi
done
```