# Regex - Renaming files with a prefix/suffix

Tags: regex, unix, batch-rename

Command below is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/208220/3470343

The command adds the word `new.` as a prefix. That's understood.

```
rename 's/(.*)$/new.$1/' original.filename
```

However, I'd like to ask why the open and close brackets are required here:

```
(.*)
```

And also why is `$1` the variable which stores the original file name, why can't I do the the same with following (where i have replaced `$1` with `$2`):

```
rename 's/(.*)$/new.$2/' original.filename
```

I'm still relatively new to bash, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with BASH. This is basic regex syntax. Read a basic regex tutorial.

Comment: Why would you expect that you could just randomly replace one variable expansion with another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, `(.*)$` is what is known as a **regular expression** (or regex). Regular expressions are used to **match** text based on some rules.

For example, `.*` matches zero or more characters. `$` matches the end of the line. Because regular expressions by default are greedy, `.*$` matches the whole line (although, precisely because regexes are greedy, `$` is superfluous).

> However, I'd like to ask why the open and close brackets are required here: `(.*)`

The round brackets denote a **group**. Groups are used to "save" the contents of the matched text, so that you can use it later.

> And also why is `$1` the variable which stores the original file name, why can't I do the the same with following (where I have replaced `$1` with `$2`): ...

In the case of `rename(1)`, the first group is stored in `$1`, the second group is stored in `$2` and so on. For example, the following regular expression:

```
(a)(b)(c)
```

stores a single `a` into `$1`, a single `b` into `$2` and so on.

There you have only one group, therefore you must use `$1`. Tokens like `$2`, `$3`, ... will be empty.

Last but not least, you could use a shorter, equivalent command:

```
 rename 's/^/new./'
```

Here `^` denotes the start of the string.